# Converting csv read hex string values to uint8_t in c++

Tags: c++, csv, hex, getline, uint8t

So I am currently able to read some hex values from a csv file using ifstream. I am able to read the values and assign them to a string variable. But I want to convert them to `uint8_t` values. So essentially I want something like this `uint8_t A = 0x41;`

I have tried `atoi` ,  `stoi` , and `strtol` but i don't seem to get any valid output.(I might be using them wrong)

```cpp
int read_csv(){
using namespace std;
ifstream fin;
fin.open("simpletrajhex.txt");
while (fin.good ()){
      char[] line;
      getline (fin, line, ',');
      uint8_t hex1 = (uint8_t)stoi(line,NULL,16);
      cout << line << " " << hex1 << endl;
    }
  return 1;
}
```

When I read my csv file i get something similar

```
0xFF
0x5F
0x02
0x00
0xFF
```

But these are strings and I need each value to be converted to `uint8_t` 
and when I try convert nothing shows up.

Comment: That compiles for you?

Comment: If you are reading a `.csv` file, don't you need to know the number of values in each line? Reading with `getline (fin, line, ',');` will not stop at the end of the line (since the delimiter is now `','`) and will simply read all csv values in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code, but two primary problems related to your conversion to `uint8_t`. A general problem with attempting to read a `.csv` file with `getline (fin, line, ',');` is you have no way of tracking the number of values present in each line. Reading with the `','` delimiter will cause `getline` to skip the line-ending and simple read the next value until `EOF` is encountered. Better to read an entire line into `line` with `getline (fin, line);` and then create a `stringstream` from `line` allowing  you to read the value in the line until the end of the stringstream is reached (limiting the value conversions to those within each line).

The primary obstacle to storing the values as `uint8_t` is your failure the **validate** the the result of the `stoi` conversion is within the range of `uint8_t` before making the assignment. Further, since `uint8_t` is an `unsigned` value, use of `stoul` is more appropriate. While the C-style cast to `(uint8_t)` is valid, it is better to use a `static_cast<uint8_t>(...)` (though both provide the same result). Finally, your attempt to output `<< hex1 ...` will always fail as the `<<` operator expects an `int` (or `unsigned`) value.

Putting all of those pieces together, you can rework your `read_csv()` to take the name of the file to open as a parameter rather than hardcoding the filename in the function (don't do that) and do something like:

```
int read_csv (const string& name)
{
    string line;
    ifstream fin (name);

    while (getline (fin, line)) {           /* read entire line into line */
        stringstream ss (line);             /* create stringstream from line */
        string field;                       /* string to hold each field */
        cout << "line: " << line << '\n';
        while (getline (ss, field, ',')) {  /* read each hex value from line */
            uint64_t tmp = stoul (field, 0, 0); /* convert to uint64_t */
            if (tmp <= UINT8_MAX) {         /* validate in range of uint8_t */
                uint8_t hex1 = static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp);   /* store uint8_t */
                /* output with cast to unsigned for << */
                cout << "  " << field << " -> " <<
                        static_cast<uint32_t>(hex1) << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**note:** rather than casing within `cout` you can also precede `hex1` with a numeric `+` to force the promotion, e.g.

```
cout << "  " << field << " -> " << +hex1 << '\n';
```

**also note:** that using `0` for the base in `stoul`, the numeric base is auto-detected: if the prefix is **0**, the base is octal, if the prefix is **0x** or **0X**, the base is hexadecimal, otherwise the base is decimal.

A short example making use of the function could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int read_csv (const string& name)
{
    string line;
    ifstream fin (name);

    while (getline (fin, line)) {           /* read entire line into line */
        stringstream ss (line);             /* create stringstream from line */
        string field;                       /* string to hold each field */
        cout << "line: " << line << '\n';
        while (getline (ss, field, ',')) {  /* read each hex value from line */
            uint64_t tmp = stoul (field, 0, 0); /* convert to uint64_t */
            if (tmp <= UINT8_MAX) {         /* validate in range of uint8_t */
                uint8_t hex1 = static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp);   /* store uint8_t */
                /* output with cast to unsigned for << */
                cout << "  " << field << " -> " <<
                        static_cast<uint32_t>(hex1) << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "error: insufficient input\n" <<
                "usage: " << argv[0] << " <file>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    read_csv (argv[1]);
}
```

(**note:** `using namespace std;` is generally encouraged, so while it can ease typing for short example programs, you will generally want to avoid including the entire `std` namespace in each source file (and especially avoid including it in header files))

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/hexcsv.csv
0xff,0x5f
0x02,0x00
0xff,0xaa
```

**Example Use/Output**

Each of the numeric values are store in the `uint8_t` variable `hex1` before being output in decimal.

```
$ ./bin/read_csv_uint8 dat/hexcsv.csv
line: 0xff,0x5f
  0xff -> 255
  0x5f -> 95
line: 0x02,0x00
  0x02 -> 2
  0x00 -> 0
line: 0xff,0xaa
  0xff -> 255
  0xaa -> 170
```

Comment: Thank you for all the clarifications and the sample code. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help. The fact that `cout` requires a promotion to `int` can really give you fits figuring out why an `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` value simply refused to print. Other than than it's just a conversion to an unsigned long and a verification that the result will fit in a `uint8_t` before the assignment. You were getting there. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store ***hex*** value as it is in an `uint8_t` variable, so `uint8_t A = 0x41` is not possible. Instead, you will have to get a ***decimal*** equivalent of the ***hex*** number into `uint8_t`.

Try using `std::stoul`

Get the ***decimal*** equivalent of ***hex*** and get the ***hex*** back from the ***decimal*** when you need it.